# Double function returning as an integer

Tags: c++

I would like to know why does my double function returns as an integer instead of a decimal. I gave a value of 0.01 to my ic4 to go into the function and expect a return of 0.384615 but instead i get a return of 1.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

double vt = 0.026;
double ic4;

double gm7(double IC7);

int main ()
{
    while(true)
    {
        printf("ao (in dB): ");
        cin >> ao;

        if (ao >= 80)
        {
            printf("IC7 (in Amps): ");
            cin >> ic7;
            cout << "IC7: " << ic7 << endl;
            gm7(ic7);
            cout <<"gm7: " << gm7 << endl;
        }
    
        else
        {
            printf("Choose another ao!\n");
        }
    }
}

double gm7 (double IC7)
{
    return IC7 / vt;
}
```

Comment: First,  you called the function but did not assign the returned value to any variable. Then, you printed the reference to the function. Everything is wrong in your code. Change `<< gm7 <<` to `<< gm7(ic7) <<`.

Comment: The posted code doesn't compile (no variable named `ao` or `ic7` is declared, etc)

Comment: `cout <<"gm7: " << gm7 << endl;` a function (not invoked) will be interpreted as a bool `true` and print out `1` (the value of `true`).

Answer (score 0):

`gm7` is a function. You are inserting a function into the character stream.

Character streams do no have an insertion operator overloads for functions. However, they do have an overload for `bool` and function pointers implicitly convert to `bool` and function implicitly converts to a function pointer. Since the function pointer is not null, it converts to `true`. `true` is printed as 1.

P.S. The example program is ill-formed because it uses undeclared names.

Answer (score 0):

just to clarify the comments

you should do this

```
int main ()
{
    while(true)
    {
        printf("ao (in dB): ");
        cin >> ao;

        if (ao >= 80)
        {
            printf("IC7 (in Amps): ");
            cin >> ic7;
            cout << "IC7: " << ic7 << endl;
            double gm7res = gm7(ic7); <======
            cout <<"gm7: " << gm7res << endl; <<======
        }
    
        else
        {
            printf("Choose another ao!\n");
        }
    }
}
```

note you also need to declare a0

Comment: `ao` still undeclared.